# PHP Post & Redirect

Tags: php

I have the following code which checks the post for a "no" and if it exists prints and error or if not it redirects.  It currently redirects everytime regardless of the fact the post array has 'NO' as a value.

```
if($_POST["minRequirementsForm"] == '1') {
     foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { 
        if ($value == 'no') {  
            $error = 1; 
        } else { 
            header('Location: mysite.com/app-stage1.php');
        }
     }
//print_r($_POST);  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `header` call *after* the loop, and check for `$error`:

```
$error = false;

if($_POST["minRequirementsForm"] == '1') {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { 
        if ($value == 'no') {  
            $error = true;
        }
    }
}

if (! $error) {
    header('Location: mysite.com/app-stage1.php');
}
```

Notice that this uses the type [`boolean`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) instead of an integer for the variable `$error`, which is more appropriate.

Comment: he doesn't wanna redirect on error. So declare the "error" other way round..  ;)

Comment: THanks guys!  As soon as i posted this i realised how dumb i was being :)

Comment: Of course if they selected yes then the IF returns true and it would redirect anyway!  Thanks again!

Comment: It's not the best way to do what you want. Check out my answer which is even more faster.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use it as you did. Just write:

```
if (in_array('no', $_POST)) { $error = true; }
if (!$error) { header('Location: mysite.com/app-stage1.php'); }
```

It's better to use an already existing functions in php than reinvent the wheel.
Or use the following, which is more appropriate:

```
if (!array_search('no', $_POST)) { header('Location: mysite.com/app-stage1.php'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

It redirects because of the subsequent values of non "no" strings. It echos the error, but due to next value, it redirects. Try exiting in the if(no) condition and you will see the error.